# ayuda como pasar de xml en java

Tags: java

Tengo que pasar de xml a java, lo que estoy haciendo primero es recoger los datos del xml a java  y no se como hacer la parte de 'repetir'. Se que tengo que crear una lista con los datos 'repetir' y luego recorrerla pero no se como introducir el código aquí`

```html
<historia>
  <paciente>
 <datos identificador="000"> 
    <nom>ingrid</nom>
    <ape>torres</ape>
 </datos>
  </paciente>
  
  
  <repetir>
    <nombres> 
      <alicante>xx</alicante>
      <valencia>xx2</valencia>
      <balears id="codigo">00</balears> 
      <leon id="cm">001</leon>
    </nombres>
    <nombres> 
      <alicante>xx</alicante>
      <valencia>xx2</valencia>
      <balears id="codigo">00</balears> 
      <leon id="cm">001</leon>
    </nombres>
    
   <nombres> 
      <alicante>xx</alicante>
      <valencia>xx2</valencia>
      <balears id="codigo">00</balears> 
      <leon id="cm">001</leon>
    </nombres>
  </repetir>

<historia>
```

Comment: Que tal @liz bienvenida a StackOverflow. Creo que serviría bastante que colocaras tu código Java que llevas hasta el momento.

Comment: eso es sólo el XML, puedes editar tu pregunta para ver tu código en java?